# How to reverse a string made of digit in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

What is the best way to turn out digits in number?

E.g.

```
$ echo 123 | hook
321
$ echo 12358 | hook
85321
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461625/bashreverse-the-order-of-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
:~> echo 123456 | rev
654321
```

It should work.
The usage is pretty simple. from man:

> NAME
>        rev - reverse lines of a file or files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        rev [file ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The rev utility copies the specified files to the standard output, reversing the order of characters in every line.  If no files are specified, the standard input is read.

If not available you should also be able to use `awk`:

```
:~> echo 123456 | awk '{ for(i=length;i!=0;i--)x=x substr($0,i,1);}END{print x}'
654321
```

Source [the unix school](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/different-ways-to-reverse-string-in.html)

If you eventually need to completly invert a file you could add `tac` to  `rev` command line like this:

```
tac myfile | rev
```

Comment: Which definition of character does it use? Byte, code-unit, code-point, or does it even a full combining character sequence?

Comment: What?  I dont understand your question

Comment: I'm interested in how well `rev` understands text (and thus charsets and unicode), or if it simply operates on bytes. Consider an input which contains characters outside ASCII. For example with UTF-8, one code-point often maps to two bytes. If you reverse the bytes, that will produce a broken output. Same for legacy multi-byte charsets like they're common in Asia. Similarly if you have a letter followed by a combining diacritic, simply reversing the code-points means that it will combine with the wrong base letter.

Comment: In fact what I didn't get the part of the question you asked for.  I have really no idea how it supports chat,  maybe the best thing to do is to test

Comment: @CodesInChaos `rev` operates on bytes, but uses the current locale to interpret them. Compare `LANG=utf8 rev file.txt` vs `LANG=C rev file.txt` for some UTF-8 encoded file with non-ASCII characters. With `utf8`, `rev` will recognize multibyte UTF-8 sequences and preserve their relative order.

Comment: @chepner, GNU `rev` reverses the order of _characters_ in each line, not bytes, not combining sequences. It will turn `Stéphane` to `enahpétS` but `Stéphane` to `enahṕetS` (that is the accent will go to the `p` instead of the `e`)

Comment: In my example, the input string contained the two bytes that form the UTF-8 encoding of U+00E9. In your example, it seems to contain the three bytes that form the UTF-8 encoding of U+0065 and U+0301, in which case the combining acute accent in the reverse string does follow the `p`, not the `e`.

Answer (score 6):

For those not limited to `bash`, with `zsh`:

```
forward=123
backward=${(j::)${(Oas::)forward}}
```

Those are variable expansion flags:

- `s::`: split on the empty string, so one element per character
- `Oa`: reverse the resulting array (`O` for reverse order, `a` for array subscript order).
- `j::`: join the elements with the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `rev`?

```
echo 123|rev
321
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xv

string="$1"
reverse_string=""
string_length="${#string}"

while (( "$string_length">=1 )) 
do
     string_length=$(( $string_length - 1 ))
     reverse_string="$reverse_string${string:$string_length:1}"
done

echo "$reverse_string"
```

make the file executable

```
$ chmod +x reverse_string
$ ./reverse_string 123456789    
98765432
```

Comment: Or somewhat more compactly: `for ((i=${#1}-1; i>=0; i--)); do echo -n "${1:i:1}"; done; echo`

Answer (score 2):

`rev` is the obvious and probably the best answer.  But `rev` is not always installed by default.  If you want to do this purely with coreutils you can use this longer command:

```
echo 123 | fold -w1 | tac | paste -d '' -s -
```

- `fold -w1` puts each digit on a line
- `tac` is a reverse `cat`, i.e. reverses the order of the lines
- `paste -d '' -s -` serially pastes the digit from each line back onto one line

Comment: Neither `rev` nor `tac` are standard Unix commands, but `rev` is a lot more _portable_ than `tac`. `tac` is GNU only. Other unices usually have `tail -r` for `tac`.

Comment: Unlike rev, this can also be used on OpenWRT.

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl:

```
echo 123 | perl -nle 'print scalar reverse $_'
```

Source: [Perl one-liners](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7328094)

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$s"
12345
6789
```

Here is a Ruby that reverses each line of input:

```
$ echo "$s" | ruby -lpe '$_=$_.reverse'
54321
9876
```

Answer (score -3):

```
s=""
for i in $*
do
    s="$i $s";
done
for j in $s
do
    echo $j
done
```

Comment: How is that answering the question?

Comment: It's clearly attempting to, it just gets it kind of wrong. He wrote a script that will output its arguments in reverse order, instead of a script that will reverse its stdin